# Springloaded's clearLocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscovererCache gives IllegalArgumentException on code recompile

Tags: spring-loaded

I'm using springloaded in a maven project (a Hippo CMS project) and all appears to work ok, but I do keep getting this error every time IDEA recompiles a class.

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 04-Aug-2017 10:50:59.743 SEVERE [FileSystemWatcher: files=#5 cl=ParallelWebappClassLoader
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   context: site
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   delegate: false
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] ----------> Parent Classloader:
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] java.net.URLClassLoader@7227c54e
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] ] org.springsource.loaded.agent.SpringPlugin.clearLocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscovererCache Unexpected IllegalArgumentException trying to access parameterNamesCache field on LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer class
```

Does anyone know if this is something serious or can be ignored as everything does work?

In case it helps, I configured the project as per this article:
https://www.bloomreach.com/en/resources/blogs/2014/08/Speeding+up+your+Hippo+CMS+development+with+Spring+Loaded.html

with this example code for tomcat 8:
https://github.com/jreijn/hippocms-spring-loaded/tree/hippo10

Versions used: JDK 1.8, Tomcat 8, Springloaded 1.2.7, IDEA 2017.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure they can be safely ignored, since:

1. They are logged as INFO messages (even though they contain the word
   "SEVERE").
2. It seems to work just fine, regardless.

I hope the springloaded library is still actively being worked on.
The latest version I tried is 1.2.9.BUILD-20171129.170623-4, which still seemed to trigger this error message.